# Tool to extract password-protected .rar without the password

Tags: windows-10, rar, password-recovery

I have a .rar file I don't know the password for.

What is the fastest software to get the password?

Comment: It would probably take less time to re-download your game than it crack that password. Your best (and only) bet is brute force.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is "rar password brute forcing". [archpr](https://www.elcomsoft.com/archpr.html) is the popular windows option. [rarcrack](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rarcrack/) and [rar2john](https://github.com/piyushcse29/john-the-ripper) are popular open options.

Comment: And with any decent password these will fail. They will only work if the rar was packed with a dictionary word or a simple derivation of one, like *p@ssw0rd* or *password123*.

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes breaking good encryption is not cheap but all you need is money to rent a cluster of hardware accelerated (CUDA) brute forcing servers from amazon... I have not found a 'passwords per second per flop' specification for the 2 types of rar encryption but did find some from a computer from the year 2000 https://www.elcomsoft.com/help/en/archpr/passwords_and_encryption.html